# xcode copy generated bundle resource delay

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a custom run script phase that generate a file that need to be copied into resource bundle.

The problem is that it take about half seconds to generate the file and Xcode always copied the old version of the file into bundle rather the newly generated one. I checked that run script phase is before copy bundle resource phase.

I can add `sleep 1` to the end of the script to force Xcode to wait but is any better way?

Comment: a bit late.. .but did you get at the bottom of this?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: we got to a stage where it fails the first time we build in a certain environment and from the second on it builds fine. Probably I will contact you in 6 years :)